GNS construction applied to $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$
I feel like the GNS construction applied to $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with trace Tr$(x_{i,j})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}x_{i,i}$ should yield $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, that is, the closure of $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})/\{(x_{i,j})\;|\;\text{Tr}((x_{i,j})(x_{i,j})^{*})=0\}$ with respect to the inner product $\langle (x_{i,j}),(y_{i,j})\rangle=\text{Tr}((x_{i,j})(y_{i,j})^{*})$. But isn't $\{(x_{i,j})\;|\;\text{Tr}((x_{i,j})(x_{i,j})^{*})=0\}=\{0\}$ since $\text{Tr}((x_{i,j})(x_{i,j})^{*})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}|x_{i,i}|^{2}\;$?

You should say what is the meaning of acronym GNS

That's right, so you get $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the Frobenius inner product, not $\mathbb{C}^n$.
Here is sort of an abstract discussion. The unique simple module $\mathbb{C}^n$ actually cannot be recovered canonically from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, in a precise sense. But the trace is canonical, so it can only produce a canonical representation of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and the only one available is the regular representation (and direct sums of it). You can recover $\mathbb{C}^n$ by considering the action of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ on any of its minimal left ideals, but these are not unique (they are generated by the matrices of rank $1$) so you have to make a non-canonical choice and pick one.
This is related to the observation that $\text{Aut}(M_n(\mathbb{C})) \cong PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (by the Skolem-Noether theorem) which means, roughly speaking, that canonical constructions starting from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ can only produce objects on which $PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$ continues to act, but $PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$ doesn't act on $\mathbb{C}^n$, only $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. This observation suggests that it might be possible to canonically recover the projective space $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^n)$, which is true; it can be recovered as the space of minimal right ideals.
